# How to pass data to an exceptionhandler?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-4

I found a tuto to manage exceptions from [this site](http://www.codejava.net/frameworks/spring/how-to-handle-exceptions-in-spring-mvc). So here is my handler :

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/adminrole")
public class AdminRole {

    ...

    @ExceptionHandler({org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException.class})
    public ModelAndView handlePkDeletionException(Exception ex) {

        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("errorPage");

        model.addObject("message", "customised message with data to display in error page");

        return model;

    }

}
```

Now I want to pass some data , for example the column name of the primary key causing the exception , to the handler in order to display a customised message in the error page. So how to pass those data to the handler ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To pass your own data to the `@ExceptionHandler` method, you need to catch the `framework exceptions` in the service layer, and throw your own `custom exception` by wrapping with the additional data.

**Service layer:**

```
public class MyAdminRoleService {
    public X insert(AdminRole adminRole) {
         try {
            //code
         } catch(ConstraintViolationException exe) {
            //set customdata from exception
            throw new BusinessException(customdata);
         }
    }
}
```

**Controller layer:**

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/adminrole")
public class AdminRole {

    @ExceptionHandler({com.myproject.BusinessException.class})
        public ModelAndView handlePkDeletionException(BusinessException ex) {
            String errorMessage  = ex.getErrorMessage(); 
            ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("errorPage");

            model.addObject("message", errorMessage);

            return model;

        }
    }
```

**P.S.:** I have taken ConstraintViolationException only as an example, but you can apply the same concept for any framework exceptions for which you wanted to add an additional data.